# H1B application after visiting the DPRK

Tags: usa, h1-visa, refusal

I'm an Indian national working towards a Master's degree in the US (F1 visa). I may apply for an H1B visa later. Would visiting countries which are on not on so great a terms with the US affect such an application? Case in point - North Korea.

Comment: Expect to be drilled with questions about the names of every single person you had contact with and why. Technically, a state of war still exists between the United States and North Korea. Usually close family relatives of those already living there are given considerable leeway. Otherwise, the scrutiny on you and your application will be high. But if it is a genuine visit for genuine reasons, there shouldn't be automatic grounds for refusal. Why do you want to go?

Comment: @ouflak: Out of curiosity, what's the precise "technical" sense in which a state of war exists?  For instance, the US never declared war on North Korea.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Such declarationns are rather passe now in modern times. To be precise, and in fear of harkoning back the old days, since North Korea is internationally recognized by some other states of repute (China, Russia, a few others) and has formally declared war by the governing articles of the day, then one can say that such a state exists. Note that there was never a historical requirement that such a declaration be bilateral. While this is more of formality now, it is a standing-in-the-bakcground point in relations between the U.S., South Korea and North Korea.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, of course it will affect your application.  With any luck, however, the effect will be minimal.

The officer examining your application will want to know why you visited the country in question, and the reason for the visit may cause them to look in more detail into whether to approve the application.

If your visit was legitimate, however, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.  Just answer any questions truthfully.  Having been in North Korea will not be an automatic problem, but being discovered in a lie will result in automatic refusal of your visa.